# c# - saveFileDialog with Custom Extensions

Tags: c#

How would I read/save/open custom file extensions designed for my program? My program reads text from a richTextBox then saves it vice versa.

Comment: Did you research this at all? There are plenty of resources for this all over the place. Not to mention the MSDN pages for the `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog`...

Comment: I am chill. Don't get so offended. I'm just saying, it's better to show a little research next time and you're more likely to post a question worthy of upvotes rather than downvotes.

Comment: Here is a link with an example of how to save a file with custom extension using RichTextBox https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4a710b1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "My custom extensions (*.extension)|*.extension";
dlg.DefaultExt = "extension";
dlg.AddExtension = true;
```

open

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "My custom extensions (*.extension)|*.extension";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
```

actually use it

go [here](https://superuser.com/questions/365596/how-do-you-make-and-run-your-own-file-extension)